# Check if jsonArray is not [[]]

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, org.json

I have this weird json Array

```
[
     [
     ]
]
```

How can I check whether this json arary is in this form or not?
I tried to check whether `jsonArray.length() > 0` but for `[[]]` this is giving me `true` but I expect to be `false`.

- How can I fix?

Comment: It returns true because it contains another empty array... So obviously your expectations are wrong

Comment: How can I check this?

Answer (score 3):

jsonArray will have a size of one as it has an empty array inside it. So, you can use this condition to check for nested empty array [ [ ] ].

```
(jsonArray.size()==1 && jsonArray[0].size()==0)
```

Comment: `size()` method does not exist because I am using `org.json JSONArray`. Any other solution?

Comment: use length in that case. I think that should work.
(jsonArray.length()==1 && jsonArray[0].length()==0)

Answer (score 0):

try this: `(jsonArray != null && jsonArray.length() == 1 && jsonArray.optJSONArray(0) != null && jsonArray.getJSONArray(0).length() == 0)`